# Is there any correspondence between speed of propagation of electromagnetic in vacuum and in a linear and homogeneous enviroment?

Tags: electromagnetism, waves

I'm looking to confirm that inside a linear and homogeneous enviroment, the speed of propagation of electromagnetic waves is different from the corresponding speed in vacuum by a factor n, that is, v = c / n. If that n factor exist, how could I find it?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refractive_index#Relative_permittivity_and_permeability

Comment: I can't believe it!
It's so obvious, thanks!!!!!